# Verbal Job offered and email confirming offer but still nothing in writing

Tags: job-search

Last Thursday 29th Dec I was telephoned to say I had been offered the job which I verbally accepted. An hour later the manager confirmed it in an email and requested my address and details of referees, saying she would copy in HR and get the paperwork started asap and confirm a start date.

I still haven't heard anything and whilst I appreciate there was a Christmas break until Tuesday 3rd I would have expected to receive some sort of communication.

I am now not actively pursuing jobs and have turned down a couple of interviews.

Any advice on what to do here please?

Note: Not a duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p), the process is further along than in that question.

Comment: It looks like found out the hard way: a verbal offer means nothing. It is not clear why you turned down interviews, but I suspect it is due to the verbal offer .. uhm, let me just say, don't do that again. As that Shaikhspear guy said once, "an interview call in hand is better than a verbal offer in the bush".

Comment: OP did mention email confirmation. At least in Finland that counts as a written and legally binding contract, even without a start date. IANAL, but I think that is the case in all EU countries.

Comment: Checking on the status, and checking on start date/contract to sign, are not the same thing.  For one thing, checking on the status is a one sided affair, checking start date and contract is at least as much to the companies benefits as the new employees--because that is what he is at this point.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the essential message of that answer remains -- you have no control over what the employer does, so contacting them does not further your cause. Until you have an offer letter, continue to take interviews. You may find a better offer in the meantime. This is probably just a routine delay, but why take the chance?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Without a start date, who would accept it? "You can start, but due to an unexpected budget change, you can't start until 2018. OK?"

Answer (score 2):

Today is 5 Jan - Email the manager. Say that you are following up on the offer they made on 29 Dec. Ask the manager if there is anything else they need from you to complete the paperwork and get back to you. And wish them a happy new year.

Answer (score 2):

In most Western countries, the period from Dec 24th to Jan 2nd is very slow. Many companies shut down entirely, and in those that don't, lots of people take vacation. I would be very surprised if even the most enthusiastic hiring manager managed to get the paperwork completed by today, January 5th. If snail-mail is involved, I would not have expected to hear anything by now.

Nonetheless it is entirely reasonable to contact the manager this week and just check that everything is still on track. Be polite and don't imply that you are impatient.